# Dual hibernation with two Linux distributions using separate swap partitions

Tags: linux, boot, multi-boot, grub, hibernate

I have three operating systems installed on my ThinkPad T450, in this order: Win10, Kubuntu 18.04, Fedora 29. 
Both Win10 and Kubuntu are installed on primary partitions, and F29 on an extended partition with LVM. F29 was installed without a bootloader (no second installation of Grub2), and has a separate swap partition from Kubuntu.

I am able to hibernate and resume from Win10 and Kubuntu without issues, this is as expected. I am unable to hibernate and resume from F29, this is expected as well(?), since I am only able to have one Grub, and in the `/etc/default/grub` configuration file, I have only specified `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=*UUID of Kubuntu's swap partition*"`
. Thus, my question is: how can I successfully suspend to disk and resume from it in F29?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly there is need for a separate partition or swap file for every OS that can be suspended to disk. Otherwise one could possibly overwrite an OS state being in hibernation state and prevent that from being resumed to that previous working situation.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57780/do-i-only-need-one-swap-partition-for-multiple-linux-distros-and-other-questio

One can add resume=/dev/'sdx swap' for each menuentry at /boot/grub2/grub.cfg .
grubby tool?
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/67758/hibernate-on-fedora-21-does-not-resume/

Comment: Hi there, thank you for taking the time to respond. Sorry if I misunderstood your response, but I already do have separate swap partitions for Kubuntu and F29, does your response still apply?

Comment: I read your updated response, I have already modified my `/etc/default/grub` to include `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=*UUID of Kubuntu's swap partition*"`, how do I apply this to my situation, is there a way to distinguish between cases?
edit: Ah, I see. So I need to modify `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` directly (and make it persist) instead of generating `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from (`/etc/default/grub` + `grub-mkconfig`), is that right?

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT=saved GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true in /etc/default/grub https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Konfiguration/#Bedeutung-der-Variablen or "savedefault" line (without quotation marks) on every menuentry in /boot/grub/grub.cfg might solve for grub2 choosing the suitable menuentry for OS and resume partition.

Comment: You can use `/etc/grub.d/NN_custom` or `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` to add your menu entries with correct resume UUIDs rather than editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` direct.  That would save it getting overwritten.

Comment: The `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` ... method did not work unfortunately. Thank you for the suggestion regarding 40_custom.cfg, I will try to write a menuentry.